# Json to OrderedDict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

Whenever I try to parse a json to an OrderedDict, it ends up in a different order than the json is. I try it like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
data = OrderedDict(json.loads(resp.read().decode("utf-8")), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Am I doing something wrong, if so, what can I do to fix it, or is it not possible in python?

I have seen things like `object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict` but that does not even execute correctly. It can't resolve the refference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the keyword argument in the wrong place, which may be clearer if we add more whitespace:

```
data = OrderedDict(
    json.loads(
        resp.read().decode("utf-8")  # one argument to json.loads
    ), 
    object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict  # second argument to OrderedDict
)
```

`OrderedDict` takes no such argument - you meant to pass it to `json.loads`, then you don't need to re-create it:

```
data = json.loads(
    resp.read().decode("utf-8"), 
    object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict
)
```

The reason you aren't seeing the order you want when you leave out the `object_pairs_hook` is that `json.loads` is creating a vanilla, unordered dictionary *then* converting it to an `OrderedDict`.